# Why do they use 'persons' rather than 'people' here?

Tags: word-choice, difference

One entry of Merriam-Webster's definitions of 'follow-up' as an adjective is:

> done, conducted, or administered in the course of following up ***persons***.

Why do they use 'persons' rather than 'people' here? This appears quite outlandish to me, since the use of 'persons' is rather rare in my experience.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why "persons" is there at all. It may have been an editorial mistake.

Comment: "*Persons* is often used in formal, legal contexts to emphasize individuals as opposed to a group." Source: https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/persons-vs-people-vs-peoples/ Also, "Many usage guides over the years have suggested that there is a clear distinction between these two words; *people* is used when referring to a collective group or indeterminate number, and *persons* serves better when referring to individuals (or a number of individuals)." from https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/people-vs-persons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [persons vs people](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72012/persons-vs-people)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of [persons](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/person-persons-or-people) is possible in very formal context:

> Persons (plural) is a very formal word. We only use it in rather legalistic contexts:

> [notice in a lift]

> Any person or *persons* found in possession of illegal substances will be prosecuted.

The dictionary may have considered the role of *following up persons* to be a very formal one.